# unable to open Android Browser using Appium on emulator or Real device

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Trying to open android browser using `appium`. I am using `genymotion` for android device emulator and wrote the following code..

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();          

capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator"); 
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");  
capabilities.setCapability("Android", true);
Driver_ST = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://URL:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

after code execution if I see on `appium` following error is appearing:

```
>info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"\/data","status":0}
> info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data
> info: [debug] Creating Chrome session
> info: [debug] Set chromedriver binary as: D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
> info: [debug] Ensuring Chromedriver exists
> info: [debug] Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9515 "`) do (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST /FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /PID %b))
> info: [debug] No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
> info: [debug] Spawning chromedriver with: D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
> info: [debug] [CHROMEDRIVER] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267521) on port 9515
> Only local connections are allowed.
> info: [debug] Making http request with opts: 
{"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.browser","androidActivity":"com.android.browser.BrowserActivity","androidDeviceSerial"}}}}
> error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200 and body was {"sessionId":"b6aa64e8f25541d3513243792337a1e7","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 33.0.1750.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)"}}
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver
> info: [debug] Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver
>     at null.<anonymous> (D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\chromedriver.js:222:12)
>     at Request._callback (D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\common.js:121:5)
>     at Request.self.callback (D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:121:22)
>     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at Request.<anonymous> (D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:985:14)
>     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\android\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:936:12)
>     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)","origValue":"Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 28735.979 ms - 214
```

So why it is giving me the error that session for `chromedriver` could not created though I am trying to open Android Browser.

Please help. Am i missing any capability or any driver which need to be installed.

Comment: what version `chromedriver` are you using?

Comment: I am using the update chrome driver and able to open the chrome browser on real device using the appium. but not the Android browser on real device or emulator.

Comment: avni, did you get any solution to your problem. I am also sailing in the same ship. Not getting any solution so far. Please help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code sample.That works.Please try to open ( Automation Name : Selendroid )

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    // set up appium
    File app = new File(SignUpElement.apkFilePath);

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

    capabilities.setCapability(GeneralElement.device, GeneralElement.deviceType);
    capabilities.setCapability(GeneralElement.emulator, GeneralElement.emulatorType);
    capabilities.setCapability(GeneralElement.platformVer, GeneralElement.platformVerType);
    capabilities.setCapability(GeneralElement.platformName, GeneralElement.platformNameType);
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        WebElementFactory.driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think u opened app thorough this code But I want to open Android Browser Not App also using the appium not selendroid.

Answer (score 0):

Automation is effected using a bundled Chromedriver server as a proxy. With 4.2 and 4.3, automation works on official Chrome browser or Chromium only. With 4.4+, automation also works on the built-in “Browser” app. Chrome/Chromium/Browser must already be installed on the device under test.

Comment: couldn't understand can u elaborate please.. The emulator I am using is having os 4.4.

Comment: try to install chrome from the play store and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Stock Browser [is not working](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4509) on real devices with Appium 1.3.6
You should wait until it will be fixed.

There should be no problems to start it on an emulator, though.
Can you try it?

Chrome works fine for real devices.

[It's not possible](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/tools/devices/deviceemulators?hl=en) to install it on Android emulator for now.

> There is a word of warning to be said about the Android emulator. At
>   the moment, there is no way to install Chrome on an Android emulator

Answer (score 0):

I set the capability `app` as `Browser` and it works for me -

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "Browser");
```

even if I give wrong device name or version, appium still discovers the attached emulator and launches browser on it. My whole set of capabilities looks as -

```
    capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "Browser");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "XXX");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "XXX");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```